# Paypal IPN: What happens if my listener doesn't send back acknowledgement upon receiving the IPN?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

It is probably not the best practice but in a simple project of mine I've been using the following link in the Emails being sent to my customers once they fill out my Google form.

> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&no_shipping=1&tax=0&amount=60&business=my@email.com&currency_code=USD&notify_url=https://example.com/myListener.php&item_name=dummy

In my listener I simply process the POST data from IPN and post it to a simple google sheet so I know whether my customers paid or not.

It's been working fine (Hundreds of transactions have been recorded without any error) until lately I read this on Paypal's IPN [instruction page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNIntro/#ipn-protocol-and-architecture)

[image]

Although it says my listener MUST respond to EVERY IPN message, I never did that, <s>nor do I think I ever got any resending messages</s>. Ironically, today while I am just writing this I noticed a recent transaction was reported twice in my Google Sheet, and this is the only abnormal record. I then sent a test payment but this time it didn't get reported twice.

I went into the Paypal account and checked IPN hisotry, the transaction in question does have "No. of retries" as "1", as the picture below shows:
[image]
So this explains why my Google Sheet shows two identical transactions. And it partly matches the behavior described in the IPN instruction page, although there is only 1 retry, in contrast to "keep retrying until my listener responds".

Anyone knows why the actual behavior is so different from what they say on their own page?

Also, since my listener is actually working <s>perfectly</s>, I don't want to touch it at this time. But will it cause potential problems if I leave it as is?

Answer (score 1):

Your IPN listener *must* reply with an HTTP 2xx success status when PayPal posts to it, or PayPal will keep retrying (up to around 20 times) until it does so.

So if the listener replies with e.g. an HTTP 4xx, 5xx, or gives no reply at all or can't be connected to -- PayPal will keep retrying.

I'm not sure what the specific confusion is here; the behavior is as described. You screenshot shows a 200 for the last status.

Comment: I updated the question. Among hundreds of successfully recorded transactions this is the only one that Paypal actually "retries" to send IPN message and it only retried once.  There are two confusions here: 1) Paypal didn't retry sending IPN message for my other transactions 2) When paypal does retry, it only retied once instead of keep retrying.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain this any more clearly. PayPal only retries when it receives a status that is not HTTP 2xx. Once it receives an HTTP 2xx status, it stops retrying. It's done.

Comment: I am not sure either how to explain my situation more clearly. I never sent HTTP 2xx status back to paypal. Why does it stop retrying or even never retry?

Comment: "I never sent HTTP 2xx status back to paypal." well then you don't understand how HTTP works, since you are in fact sending that status back in all but one case, it's the normal status

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.